# Date Math - How to avoid DST

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dst

I am doing some operations on dates. I've checked tutorials so to increment date by one day I make sure that date is converted to 'ms' and I simply add '86400000'.
Problem appears when I pass DST change dates.

I would like to avoid using any conditions to check dates, because I use them in some loops, where I can compare them to other dates. Having extra IF may heavily impact efficiency, especially that within a few thousands of entries it may change only 2-3 times.

I tried to change

```
"timeZone": "Europe/London"
```

in appscript.json to "Japan" (they don't use DST) but nothing happened.

Is there a simple solution to this problem or do I have to make some workaround code or extra conditions? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the part of the code where I check and compare dates.

```
     var dayMS = 24*60*60*1000;
      var check_date = variables_sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue().getTime(); //get starting date
  for (var i=1; i<=length; i++) {
    if (check_date == Dates_Table[i][0].getTime())
    {
      sum = sum + Flow_Table[i][0]; //make a sum of values from the same date
    }
    else {
      target_sheet.appendRow([new Date(check_date), "B", "C", sum, Balance_Table[i-1][0]]); //write consolidated days with sum
      check_date = check_date+dayMS;   //increment days   
      i--;     //go back
      sum = 0; //reset sum

    }

  };
```

Comment: Do everything in milliseconds since epoch (i.e. the result of `getTime()`). This is always based on UTC, so time zones are of no consequence until you need to serialize the object back to the user.

Comment: Everything happens in loop where i use 

check_date = check_date+dayMS

Both are values in ms, yet while my counter passes time change it bugs out during 

if (check_date == another_date_in_ms)

So i'd checked values that are being held in chec_date and when i add 24h on time it wrong from this time, because those days have 25 and 23h.

Comment: then use `the_date.setDate(the_date.getDate() + 1)`? Note that if you are reading a timestamp from a sheet it likely has its own hours, minutes, seconds, and ms data too, so unless you've zeroed those out, it can be tricky to get a millisecond- level match.

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your question, "how to avoid DST" - you can't.  Local time in many time zones has DST.  You can't *avoid* it - instead you have to use APIs that account for it.

Because you've assigned `dayMS` to equal 24 hours, you're working against this.  Days with the typical 1 hour DST transitions can be 23 or 25 hours long. It's also possible to have transitions that are 30 minutes long, which might be due to DST (in at least one time zone), or just because there is a change in the time zone's standard time offset.

Thus, when computing days, don't assume they are a fixed unit of time.  They vary in the same way that each month has a different number of days, and in how leap years have one more day than common years.  Think, "date math != time math".

In your above code, there's no need to call `getTime()` ever.  Just keep the values as `Date` objects, and use the mechanism that tehhowch pointed out in the question comments.  In other words, after you remove all `.getTime()` occurrences, advance the date with:

```
check_date.setDate(check_date.getDate() + 1 ));
```

This *mutates* the `check_date` variable, so there is no assignment.

This is mostly fine, but there is one problem with this approach - which is that if the resulting value lands right in the middle of a "gap" (such as the one created by the spring-forward DST transition), it will be adjusted to some other legitimate value.  Depending on Google's app-script implementation, it might adjust forward or it might adjust backward (I'm not sure which off-hand).  This might be fine for a single occurrence, but I doubt you'd then want to use that adjusted value going forward.  Thus, it may be safer to track an integer number of days from the base date in a separate variable (say, `x`) - then instead of advancing `check_date` one day at a time, you'd recreate `check_date` each pass of the loop and add `x` days.